# Is it possible to add stroke to text in ffmpeg?

Tags: text, ffmpeg, stroke

I would like to add black stroke to text in ffmpeg. Is it possible?

```
-c:v libx264 -vf "hue=h=0, drawtext=fontfile=../bin/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf:text='Hello.':fontcolor=white: fontsize=158: x=0+(w-text_w)/2: y=50+(h-text_h-line_h)/2" -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p ../bin/ENG_01.mov
```

Answer (score 8):

You can change border-color and width of border by using drawtext and adding these parameters

```
bordercolor=black:
borderw=5:
```

Your code will look

```
-c:v libx264 \
-vf "hue=h=0,\
  drawtext=fontfile=../bin/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf:\
   text='Hello.':\
   bordercolor=white:\
   borderw=5:\
   fontcolor=white:\
   fontsize=158:\
   x=0+(w-text_w)/2: y=50+(h-text_h-line_h)/2"\
 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p \
../bin/ENG_01.mov
```

Answer (score 5):

It's easier to use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter instead of [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) to add a full stroke.

## subtitles filter

[image]

`ffmpeg` will apply the `Outline` and `OutlineColour` options set in ASS files.  Or you can manually set these in the `ffmpeg` command which is useful for other subtitle formats that don't support a stroke:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "subtitles=your_subtitles_file.srt:force_style='Outline=5,OutlineColour=&H000000&'" output
```

From [Advanced Substation Alpha Tags](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/):

> The color codes are given in hexadecimal in Blue Green Red order. Note
> that this is the opposite order of HTML color codes. Color codes must
> always start with `&H` and end with `&`. Default `OutlineColour` is
> black (`&H000000&`).

## drawtext filter

[image]

Use the `borderw` and `bordercolor` options:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "drawtext=text='drawtext stroke':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white:borderw=4:bordercolor=black:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" output
```

- `bordercolor` can accept hexadecimal values and you can also change the stroke opacity, such as with `bordercolor=#ffcc00@0.5`.
- See the [drawtext filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) for more info.